# Can aria-label be used on the title element

Tags: wai-aria

I have a page where the `<title>` tag contains some text (specifically: the department name) that screen readers do not pronounce very well (the department's name is ‘AskHR’ -- it’s the HR department’s helpdesk).

I want to provide screen readers with a more pronounceable version (‘Ask H R’) whilst keeping the more stylised version for visual display. I was thinking of using `aria-label` to achieve this, but I’m uncertain whether it can be applied to the `<title>` element in the `<head>`.

Can anyone confirm whether or not this is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is valid.

First not all screen readers are made equal!

What you're trying to do may work in some but not in others. For example VoiceOver reads out "AskHR" as you would expect. (And ignores the `aria-label` attribute.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title aria-label="xxx">AskHR</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button aria-label="close">X</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think this is perhaps closer to what you're trying to do but support is limited:

```css
.label {
  speak-as: spell-out
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style/speak-as

If we inspect the example above in Chrome, you see this for the `<button>` element:

*The `aria-label` attribute takes over the button content. VoiceOver reads out "close" instead of "x".*

[image]

However this is what we see for `<title>`:

[image]

Comment: Cheers for that, @customcommander. Yeah, looks like I may be out of luck. 'speak-as' is intriguing but, as a css property, it presumably cannot be applied to a head element which, as your Web Inspector screenshot shows, is 'not rendered'. In this case it's not a huge deal; the HTML page in question is actually an email template and, as the email is almost certainly never going to be viewed in a browser, the title element will likely be ignored by the email client. I was just trying to dot all the 'i's and cross all the 't's, is all. Thanks for your input, in any case.